# How to pass parameter 'request' in POST payload using Java Rest client?

Tags: java, rest, post

I calling rest api from Java rest client.
[geoanalytics](http://geoanalytics.tibco.com/documentation/api-batchgeocoder.html)

[image]

```html
private static void BatchGeoCodingProcess() throws JSONException, ClientProtocolException, IOException {
    System.out.println("BatchGeoCodingProcess...................................");  
/*
 
 {
  "coder": {
    "addresses": [
      {
        "id": "2824",
        "countrycode": "FR",
        "longitude": "2.33",
        "latitude": "48.88",
        "maxdist": "20000"
      },
      {
        "id": "6404",
        "countrycode": "FR",
        "street": "1598 ROUTE DE QUARANTE SOUS",
        "zipcode": "78630",
        "city": "ORGEVAL"
      }
    ]
  },
  "encoding": "utf-8"
}
   
 */
    JSONObject req = new JSONObject();
 
  JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();
  req.put("request", jsonObj);
  
  JSONObject coder = new JSONObject();
  jsonObj.put("coder", coder);
  jsonObj.put("encoding", "utf-8");
  JSONArray addrList = new JSONArray();
  coder.put("addresses", addrList);
  
  // Reverse geo code
  JSONObject addr = new JSONObject();
  addr.put("id", "2824");
  addr.put("countrycode", "FR");
  addr.put("longitude", "2.33");
  addr.put("latitude", "48.88");
  
  addrList.put(addr);
  
  // geo code
  addr = new JSONObject();
  addr.put("id", "6404");
  addr.put("countrycode", "FR");
  addr.put("street", "1598 ROUTE DE QUARANTE SOUS");
  addr.put("zipcode", "78630");
  addr.put("city", "ORGEVAL");
  
   addrList.put(addr);
   HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
 
   HttpPost request = new HttpPost("http://geowebservices.maporama.com/demo/batchcoder.json?maporamakey=2u7kdn4DnYE=&");
   request.addHeader("content-type", "application/json");
   //request.addHeader("Accept", "application/json");
   
      System.out.println("test = "+req.toString());
   StringEntity body = new StringEntity(req.toString());
   request.setEntity(body);
   
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
    int code = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
    String reason = response.getStatusLine().getReasonPhrase();
    String test = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
    System.out.println("Code = "+code+" :: Reason = "+reason);
    System.out.println("Batch geocode");
    System.out.println("test..."+test);
    System.out.println("Batch geocode");
    
 }
```

Comment: What's the error you're seeing? Can't help much without it...

Answer (score 0):

Used

```
List<NameValuePair> urlParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        urlParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("request", jsonObj.toString()));
```

and
Commented

```
request.addHeader("content-type", "application/json");
```